# Global stability of ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

Suppose we have an ODE in $\mathbb{R}^4$
$$\dot{x}=Dx +E(x)x$$
for a diagonal matrix $D$ with negative entries and a diagonal matrix $E=(-\mu_1(x_1), \mu_1(x_2), -\mu_2(x_3), \mu_2(x_4))$.

1. for every initial point $x_0$ with nonnegative entries the trajectories are bounded.
2. $\mu:[0,\infty[$ is concave, postive except at $\mu(0)=0=\mu(\infty)$

Then, every solution (with nonnegative starting point) is asymptotically stable? Can I slightly change the ODE (or its properties) in order to obtain asymptotically stability?

Comment: Doesn't $\mu(0)=0=\mu(\infty)$ exclude a convex function, because the second derivative (Hessian) is not positive (positive definite)?

Comment: you are right. I am trying to say another thing.

Comment: Interesting question but you should check your $E$. Are the signs correct? And did you intend to have $\mu_2$ in all coordinates? It would be easier if you would simply write out your ODE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. As $D$ and $E(x)$ are both diagonal, then your system is uncoupled and reduces to 4 independent scalar ODEs of the form
$$
x'=-\lambda x+\mu(x)x,
$$
where $\lambda>0$ and $\mu(x)$ is continuous and $\mu(0)=0$.

As $\mu(0)=0$, then there exists a $\xi>0$, such that 
$$
|x|<\xi\Longrightarrow \mu(x)<\frac{\lambda}{2}.
$$
Now for $|x_0|<\xi$ the IVP 
$$
x'=-\lambda x+\mu(x)x, \quad x(0)=x_0,
$$
is asymptotically stable. To see this, if $\varphi(t)$ is a solution, then, due to continuity of $\varphi$, there is a $T>0$, such that $|\varphi(t)|<\xi$ is $[0,T]$. Thus, in $[0,T]$ we have that
$$
\varphi'(t)-(-\lambda+\mu(\varphi(t)))\varphi(t)=0 \Longrightarrow
\varphi(t)=x_0\exp\left(\int_0^t (-\lambda+\mu(\varphi(s)))\,ds\right)
$$
and hence, for all $t\in [0,T]$.
$$
|\varphi(t)|\le x_0\exp(-\lambda t/2).
$$
This implies that $\varphi(t)$ remains bounded by $\xi$, for all $t>0$, and 
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty} \varphi(t)=0.
$$